# Name is not defined error inside a function, despite using global variable, it's being ignored | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The first block of code before the `sendhelp()` function works fine, the second block of code too, but when the function executes, It gives me an `name 'defualt_mode' is not defined` error, despite using  `global`, it totally gets ignored, since when I remove it, it gives me the same error, WHAT? What I want to happen is to have it accept the default variable, but without removing the function and without manually defining it inside the function.
What I mean by 'manually' :

```
def sendhelp():

    defualt_mode = True

        
    if defualt_mode is True:

        #list of accounts
        account_list = ["tech.dailys", "technologyhive", "rising.tech", "fanastic.technology", "xtechnation", "technology", "fundamentaltech", "techsector"]
```

Also if there are any alternatives to using global that'd be awesome (without removing the `sendhelp()` function)

```
message_response = ['/V/M/itechexplore, bruh, fam, dawg', 'dksasadj', 'jdsjsalkd', 'kalsdn']


for message in message_response:

    if '/V/M/' in message:

        pre_account_list= []
        multiple_account_scan_accounts = message.removeprefix("/V/M/")
        

        pre_account_list.append(multiple_account_scan_accounts)
        

        for message in pre_account_list:
            if "," in message:
                pre2_account_list = message.split(", ")
        
        print(pre2_account_list)
            
        default_mode = False


    if '/V/M/R/' in message:

        
        default_mode = True



def sendhelp():

    #checks if the defualt list is active
    global defualt_mode

        
    if defualt_mode is True:

        #list of accounts
        account_list = ["tech.dailys", "technologyhive", "rising.tech", "fanastic.technology", "xtechnation", "technology", "fundamentaltech", "techsector"]



if default_mode is True or default_mode is False:
    sendhelp()
```

Comment: You must first have a global variable before you can use the global variable in a function. In other words `global default_list` just says *"use the global variable of `default_list`, don't create or look for a local variable with the same name!".* But since you haven't defined the global you get an error.

Comment: Alternatives to using globals is to pass them into function. Look up how to define functions that can take input as it's really important to know.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman but isn't default_list already a global variable, since it's not inside a function or anything

Comment: According to your code it is inside the function `sendhelp`

Comment: Okay, but `default_mode` is only declared inside the if statement of the for loop, so if neither the for loop or the if statement are entered, then the value isn't defined and you'll get the error.

Comment: Note also you've mispelt the varaible as `defualt_mode` in sendhelp(). And `default_mode is True or default_mode is False` is always true.

Comment: Never mind man I've made a severe and continuous lapse of my judgement loooool. I can't even begin to explain. This helped solve the problem among many others, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` statement of `sendhelp()` function, you are checking for `defualt_list` value to be True.
You have just declared the variable but it is not initialized.
Before if statement if you pass

```py
defualt_list = True
```

or

```py
defualt_list = False
```

Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement as follows (note, I assume you're aware sendhelp does nothing in either case at the moment. It either defines then throws away account_list, or does nothing, then returns.

```
def sendhelp(default_mode):
    if default_mode is True:
        #list of accounts
        account_list = ["tech.dailys", "technologyhive", "rising.tech", "fanastic.technology", "xtechnation", "technology", "fundamentaltech", "techsector"]


sendhelp(default_mode)
```